Xfce malfunction in Debian
I’m running xfce in Debian 12 bookworm and a couple of days ago all the buttons on top of the windows to close or maximise them etc., disappeared. The interface is acting weird to. I think this might have something to with the fact that I recently tried to boot kali in VirtualBox, and that I may have accepted to do some modifications or so to the hard drive during the text-installation process. Gnome and KDE both work fine and I have tried to delete xfce and then reinstall but nothing works. What should I do?


It has nothing to do with Virtualbox. 2. Instead of trying to "delete xfce and then reinstall", something you can't easily do you should reinstall the 2 metapackages with an argument which is something you certainly didn't.


Reinstall the XFCE DE by forcing the re-installation of the metapackages it depends on in Debian:
sudo apt install --reinstall xfce4 xfce4-goodies

Reboot.
Source

Thank you for the answer :)! It didn’t work though :(. I tried running  the command from several different window managers and then rebooting but unfortunately nothing works.

What do you exactly by*"running the command from several different window managers"*? It doesn't depend on any particular DE, obviously. Were there any errors?
